# Why is my GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged event not firing frequently?

Tags: c#, xna, geolocation

I have a wrapper class which starts and stops a `GeoCoordinateWatcher` object and have set the `MovementThreshold` to 0 because I am implementing a navigational kind of app/game on Windows Phone 7 using XNA. However, the `PositionChanged` event is not firing correctly. Most of the times it fires 3 or 4 times and just gets stuck, but it also works perfectly sometimes and I have no idea why. In the `GameScreen.Update()` I am checking if the watcher is started and starting it if it isn't. I stop the watcher when the player exits the game via the home button or presses the back button.

P.S.: On the emulator it works flawlessly all the time so I'm inclined to think it's something to do with the device. The GPS signal is fine though because I've tried it in the streets as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have a weak GPS signal where I live so problem solved.